# Call for Prior Art US Patent 8,738,435 (Phoenix Licensing)

Tags: online-advertising, internet, customization

CALL FOR PRIOR ART. Can you find prior art for this patent that claims novelty based on customizing online content using a user's preferences?

Check out [Google Patents](http://www.google.com/patents/US8738435) for full details about this particular application.

**"Method and apparatus for presenting personalized content relating to offered products and services"**

**BASIC PATENT DATA:**

- **Publication Number**: US8738435 B2
- **Assignee**: LPL Licensing, LLC (Phoenix Licensing)
- **Priority Date**: Jun 10, 1996

**PATENT OVERVIEW:**

US Patent 8,738,435 claims the idea of sending a personalized marketing message using a computer.

Claim 1 of the patent is representative (the claims are supposed to describe the boundaries of the invention). It claims a “method of generating a set of personalized communications … with a computer system.” The steps are described at an extremely high level of abstraction, including things such as “accessing a computer-accessible storage medium” using “identifying content to distinguish each person from other persons.” The patent plainly proposes using ordinary computers to achieve this task. In fact, the “preferred embodiment of the apparatus” is illustrated in Figure 1 and includes fascinating, non-obvious details like a “display,” a “keyboard,” and a “mouse or pointing device." [image]